# how to get indexes of elements in MatrixSymbol

Tags: python, sympy

i generate two matrices :

y=MatrixSymbol('y', n, k)

T=MatrixSymbol('T', n,k) , where

n=k=3

then I get expressions :

1. Matrix([[y[0, 2] + 11.0 * y[1, 2] - 12.0 * y[2, 2] + 195.0*exp(-100000/(5819.8 * T[1] + 5819.8))*y[1, 1] * y[1, 2] + 195.0 * exp(-100000/(5819.8 * T[1] + 5819.8)) * y[1, 1]]])

and

2. Matrix([[-y[1, 2] + y[2, 2]]])

i would like to get for 1) a set of variables : { y[0,2] , y[1,2] , y[2,2] , T[1] , y[1,1] }

and for 2) set of variables : { y[1,2] , y[2,2] }

command results .free_symbols and .args do not suit me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get those elements:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.matrices.expressions.matexpr import MatrixElement

n=k=3
y=MatrixSymbol('y', n, k)
T=MatrixSymbol('T', n,k)

M1 = Matrix([[y[0, 2] + 11.0 * y[1, 2] - 12.0 * y[2, 2] + 195.0*exp(-100000/(5819.8 * T[1] + 5819.8))*y[1, 1] * y[1, 2] + 195.0 * exp(-100000/(5819.8 * T[1] + 5819.8)) * y[1, 1]]])
M2 = Matrix([[-y[1, 2] + y[2, 2]]])

print(M1.atoms(MatrixElement))
# out: {y[0, 2], y[1, 1], T[0, 1], y[1, 2], y[2, 2]}
print(M2.atoms(MatrixElement))
# out: {y[1, 2], y[2, 2]}
```